# Solving a system of xor equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, boolean-algebra

How can I solve the following system of xor equations?

```
k0 ⊕ k2 ⊕ k3 = 0011
k0 ⊕ k2 ⊕ k4 = 1010
k0 ⊕ k1 ⊕ k2 ⊕ k3 = 0110
```

How can I solve this system to know the result for `k0 ⊕ k1 ⊕ k2 ⊕ k4` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you xor all the equations together?  (Remember, $k\oplus k=0$).

Comment: Indeed! It is actually so simple the answer is right in front of me. `1111` is the result of `k0 ⊕ k1 ⊕ k2 ⊕ k4` using the basis that k ⊕ k = 0. Thanks!

Comment: @Calvin: Glad to help!